# Custom picture for button in Android?

Tags: android, json

I want to implement a star as a button in Android so that when a user wants to favorite their 'current settings' they touch the star, which then turns yellow.

How would you do this? Can you change the default button? Or can you just import the picture and then set like an OnTouchListener?

If someone could also tell me how to import a picture (star), that would be beneficial as well.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) that has the star as it's background. Then you can register a listener for when the button is pressed to either show or remove the star.

Note: removing the star is equivalent to setting the imagebutton's background to null in most cases.

To import the star, put it in your "res/drawables" directory and then reference it in xml or in your Java code.

Comment: Ok so ImageButton instead of Button? Then the rest would be the same?

Comment: Yep! http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/ -- That doesn't use a star, but it shows how to use an image button.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will mark your answer as the correct one as soon as the website lets me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your button background when ever user clicks on it you just need to have two image for star one is for selected mode and another is for unselected mode.

So when ever user click you can toggle the selection and sets the desired image as background.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check RatingBar which is a star.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html

A RatingBar is an extension of SeekBar and ProgressBar that shows a rating in stars. The user can touch/drag or use arrow keys to set the rating when using the default size RatingBar. The smaller RatingBar style ( ratingBarStyleSmall) and the larger indicator-only style (ratingBarStyleIndicator) do not support user interaction and should only be used as indicators.

When using a RatingBar that supports user interaction, placing widgets to the left or right of the RatingBar is discouraged.

The number of stars set (via setNumStars(int) or in an XML layout) will be shown when the layout width is set to wrap content (if another layout width is set, the results may be unpredictable).

The secondary progress should not be modified by the client as it is used internally as the background for a fractionally filled star.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"  android:numStars="1"/>
```